Linux Redhat9: kernel warnings: user: probe of wq1.0 failed with error -95
I have linux Redhat 9 on intel x64 machine and I see following warnings during boot in dmesg:
user: probe of wq1.0 failed with error -95 
user: probe of wq1.1 failed with error -95 
user: probe of wq1.2 failed with error -95 
user: probe of wq1.3 failed with error -95 
user: probe of wq1.4 failed with error -95 
user: probe of wq1.5 failed with error -95 
user: probe of wq1.6 failed with error -95 
user: probe of wq1.7 failed with error -95 
user: probe of wq3.0 failed with error -95
user: probe of wq3.1 failed with error -95 
user: probe of wq3.2 failed with error -95 
user: probe of wq3.3 failed with error -95
user: probe of wq3.4 failed with error -95
user: probe of wq3.5 failed with error -95 
user: probe of wq3.6 failed with error -95 
user: probe of wq3.7 failed with error -95 

I have kernel 5.14.0-427.18.1
Does anyone know what are these warnings?
Thank you.
Should I ignore them or can I do something to fix the issue?

did you install any third-party kernel modules? This looks like debug output you'd see from a kernel module in development, trying to find the hardware it's being written for.
